# File not found when creating a package

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package

This the first time trying to create a [Nuget](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/schema/nuspec) package .

I try to run the following command :

```
nuget.exe pack Package.nuspec
```

But i get the following exception :

> NuGet.exe : File not found: 'Site1.Master'. At line:1 char:10
>   + nuget.exe <<<<  pack Package.nuspec
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (File not found: 'Site1.Master'.:String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

---

The files section in `Package.nuspec` is like this :

```
<files>
    <file src="Site1.Master" target="content\Site1.Master" />
    <file src="Site1.Master.cs" target="content\Site1.Master.cs" />
    <file src="Site1.Master.cs.designer" target="content\Site1.Master.cs.designer" />
</files>
```

---

My Sample Solution is like this :

[image]

---

**The Directory :**

[image]

Comment: Its not a file i fear @mason iirc visual studio just groups them together. Remove the first line Anyname and try again.

Comment: @Mafii Could you clarfiy where the problem please , i want to package a master page

Comment: Try removing `<file src="Site1.Master" target="content\Site1.Master" />` and run the command again. What happens then?

Comment: Paths are relative - is the nuspec file in the same folder as the Site.Master file?

Comment: @Mafii : remove it but the same error with the second file `Site1.Master.cs`

Comment: @ste-fu No,i edit the question and set screen shot of the directory   i see the `nuspec file` in the solution but out of the web application , when i try to put it  in the same project  i get another exception 
`Get.exe : Could not find file 'C:\Users\rome\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication1\Package.nuspec'.`

Comment: @ste-fu :You are right , it's relative so i should write it like this : `WebApplication1\Site1.Master`,Thanks  alot

Comment: @ste-fu you should write an answer then!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Paths in a .nuspec file are always relative to the location of the .nuspec file itself. Either the file name is wrong, or the directory path is wrong.